I want to restart vsftpd service everday on 6:00 AM, but this script restart the service every minute from 6-7AM. What should I do?
Here's the timer vsftpd-restart.timer
[Unit]
Description=Restart vsftpd daily at 6 AM
After=network.target

[Timer]
Unit=vsftpd-restart.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 06:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

This is the script vsftpd-restart.service
[Unit]
Description=Restart vsftpd daily at 6 AM
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'systemctl stop vsftpd; systemctl start vsftpd'

[Install]
WantedBy=vsftpd-restart.timer

And here's the vsftpd systemctl log
Oct 07 06:00:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:00:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:00:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:00:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:00:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:01:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:01:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:01:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:01:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:01:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:02:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:02:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:02:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:02:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:02:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:03:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:03:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:03:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:03:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:03:02 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:04:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:04:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:04:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:04:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:04:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:05:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:05:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:05:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:05:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:05:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:06:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:06:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:06:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:06:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:06:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:07:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:07:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:07:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:07:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:07:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:08:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:08:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:08:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:08:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:08:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:09:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:09:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 07 06:09:01 test systemd[1]: Stopped vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:09:01 test systemd[1]: Starting vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:09:01 test systemd[1]: Started vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server.
Oct 07 06:10:01 test systemd[1]: Stopping vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server...
Oct 07 06:10:01 test systemd[1]: vsftpd.service: Deactivated successfully.


daily restart looks a lot more like a bandaid ;p (one can use cron(8) instead) although i'd address the root cause with vsftp, so you wouldn't even need to restart it daily at the first place ;-)

The reason your current setup is causing the vsftpd service to restart every minute from 6:00 to 7:00 AM is due to the OnCalendar=--* 06:00:00 timer being persistent (Persistent=true). This means the timer attempts to "catch up" on missed events during the time the system was off, so if the system was off at 6 AM, it can lead to multiple triggers when the system comes back online. This should do it:
vsftpd-restart.timer
[Unit]
Description=Restart vsftpd daily at 6 AM
After=network.target

[Timer]
Unit=vsftpd-restart.service
OnCalendar=*-*-* 06:00:00
AccuracySec=1min  # Optional: Adds a margin to avoid precision issues
Persistent=false  # Ensures it only triggers at the exact time and doesn't catch up on missed triggers

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

And don't forget to reload with the new timer script:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd-restart.timer


I've changed the vsftpd-restart.timer and reload it but it's still restart every minutes.

Try to change the time to this please 06:01:01 or 05:59:59

Thanks a lot, it works. I changed the time to 05:59:59 and this morning it restart the service just once.

Nice, I don't know the use case, but for me this is more like a trick rather than a real way to properly manage a service, I would recommend using a cron job for this, I think it will be more easy to control.
